# Checking if a list is sorted in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm working on re-creating some basic racket functions for a project.

For this, I need to define a function that takes a comparison argument, and a list, and checks if the list is sorted based on that argument. I obviously can't just use 'sorted?'. Here's what I have so far:

```
    (define (my-sorted? lst)
  (λ (x)
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((eq? (length lst) 1) #t)
        ((x (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
         (my-sorted? (cdr lst)))
        (else #f))))
```

I don't think I'm applying the comparison function right, any help? A standard output for this should be something like:

```
(my-sorted? < '(2 5 6 9))
#t
```

While I'm at it, I'm having trouble with a slightly different function as well. This one decides if the passed in comparison is a member of the list, kinda similar. Here's what I got:

```
(define (is-member? lst x)
  (cond
    [(empty? list) false]
    [(= (car list) x) true] ;here is the error i think
    [else (is-member? (rest list) x)]))
```

Any help or guidance on fixing these is super appreciated, I can't seem to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your first function returns a function:

```
(define (my-sorted? lst)
  ; one expression, a function is returned
  (λ (x)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((eq? (length lst) 1) #t)
          ((x (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
           (my-sorted? (cdr lst)))
          (else #f))))
```

The problem with this is that your recursion also returns a function that needs to be applied in the same manner. Thus your function, when gived a comparator, will run one step and return a function that needs a new comparator.. You could solve this by applying it with the previous value:

```
(define (my-sorted? lst)
  (λ (x)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((eq? (length lst) 1) #t)
          ((x (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
           ((my-sorted? (cdr lst)) x)) ; apply returned function with x
          (else #f))))
```

Or separate it:

```
(define (my-sorted? lst)
  (λ (x)
    (define (helper lst) ; keep the recursion away from the contract
      (cond ((null? lst) #t)
            ((eq? (length lst) 1) #t)
            ((x (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
             (helper? (cdr lst)))
            (else #f)))
    (helper lst)))
```

In your second function you use `list` as if it was a value and not a function. `list` is a library function that returns a list of its arguments. You cannot do `car` on a function. You are also not using the list parameter `lst` so I guess you are mixing the two?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function like this

```
(my-sorted? < '(2 5 6 9))
#t
```

you have to make the argument list look like it - you need an operator `<` and a list as an argument.

```
(define (my-sorted? operator lst)
  (cond ((or (null? lst)
             (= (length lst) 1))
         #t)
        ((operator (first lst) (second lst))
         (my-sorted? operator (rest lst)))
        (else #f)))
```

Your second problem has its source in a typo in the line you suspected:
`list` is the name of a function. And you correct it to `lst` your function arguments variable, then it works.
Currently, your `is-member?` will work only on list of numbers, since the equality tester `=` is working reliably only for numbers.
Consider `eql`, `equal` and other equality tests...